# PHP Regex for the following

Tags: php, regex

I Have a Variable which contain following elements

```
$value= ' ["1","7.9","12\/01\/2015"] ';
```

Now I want to make a array so, that it will contain following values :-

```
$array[0] = 7.9;
$array[1] = 12/01/2015;
```

i want PHP Regex which can able to seprate the following element in the above manner.
i tryed

```
$ans = preg_match('/^[0-9,]+$/', $value);
```

But this will not work.
Plz Help what to do.
to get the array with the above manner.

```
array[0] = 7.9; //amount
array[1]= 12/01/2015; //Date
```

Comment: did you want the values inside double quotes? Why you don't want `1` does the amount must have a decimal point?

Comment: The syntax of `$value= " ["1","7.9","12\/01\/2015"] ";` looks incorrect. Did you mean to enclose it in single quotes? You could possibly use `explode` if you want to separate a string by a delimiter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your value `" ["1","7.9","12\/01\/2015"] "` seems to me to be a json encoded array, I'd use `json_decode` to get what you want:

```
$value = ' ["1","7.9","12\/01\/2015"] ';
$array = json_decode(trim($value));//remove leading and trailing spaces
//or as pointed out to me in the comments
$array = json_decode($value);
//remove first element ($array is now [1, 7.9, 12/01/2015]
$result = array_slice($array, 1);
var_dump($result);//array(7.9, 12/01/2015)
```

This is assuming the double quotes around the values (1, 7.9 and the date) are properly escaped, because as it stands, `$value` is not a valid string.

## [codepad demo](http://codepad.org/WZDU2CdB)

Using regex like `/[^\/\.,"]+[\.\/][^"\.,]+/` would work, too, but all in all, that's not to be recommended here. Still, for completeness:

```
preg_match_all('/[^\/\.,"]+[\.\/][^"\.,]+/', $value, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: No need to call `trim()` before `json_encode()`. Whitespace is allowed in JSON.

Comment: Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array,

Comment: @Sidj: copy pasted on phpfiddle, writecodeonline and [codepad](http://codepad.org/WZDU2CdB), worked fine every time

Comment: I am using CURL to capture that $value Data & when using it Its not working.

Comment: @Sidj: dump the raw response, because going on what you've posted here, my answer should work...